# Can someone explain how do I rotate a matrixes rows and columns in C?

Tags: c, matrix

The problem is that I have a solution for one of the exam questions; however, I do not know why a certain method is used, plus I cannot find an explanation online.

In the code below, it is asked to input a matrix with numbers bigger than `9`. If the number is smaller, then replace all the places without an input with a `0`.

Then we check whether or not the number inserted is divided by the sum of its first and last digit. If so, then proceed. If not then replace the number with `100`.

Finally, I have to rotate the column one place up if they have that change of `100`.

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int mat[50][50] = {
    0
  }, i, j, kol, red, k = 0, pom = 0, br, m, p, niz[250], sum = 0, nizpom[100], pom1, q, pom2;

  printf("Insert dimension of matrix: ");
  scanf("%d", & m);
  printf("\nInsert elements of matrix: ");
  for (red = 0; red < m && pom == 0; red++) {
    for (kol = 0; kol < m && pom == 0; kol++) {
      scanf("%d", & br);
      if (br > 9) {
        mat[red][kol] = br;
      } else
        pom = 1;
    }
  }

  printf("\nInserted matrix is: ");
  printf("\n");
  for (red = 0; red < m; red++) {
    for (kol = 0; kol < m; kol++) {
      printf("%d\t", mat[red][kol]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  for (red = 0; red < m; red++) {
    for (kol = 0; kol < m; kol++) {
      if (mat[red][kol] != 0) {
        p = 0;
        pom1 = mat[red][kol];
        do {
          nizpom[p] = pom1 % 10;
          pom1 /= 10;
          p++;

        } while (pom1 > 0);

        sum = nizpom[0] + nizpom[p - 1];

        if (mat[red][kol] % sum != 0) {
          mat[red][kol] = 100;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  printf("\nTransformed matrix is: ");
  printf("\n");
  for (red = 0; red < m; red++) {
    for (kol = 0; kol < m; kol++) {
      printf("%d\t", mat[red][kol]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  for (kol = 0; kol < m; kol++) {
    for (red = 0; red < m; red++) {
      if (mat[red][kol] == 100) {
        pom2 = mat[0][kol];

        for (red = 0; red <= m - 2; red++) {
          mat[red][kol] = mat[red + 1][kol];
        }

        mat[m - 1][kol] = pom2;

      }
    }

  }

  printf("\nRotated matrix looks like this: ");
  printf("\n");
  for (red = 0; red < m; red++) {
    for (kol = 0; kol < m; kol++) {
      printf("%d\t", mat[red][kol]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

}
```

This part of the code I do not understand,because I do not know how to rotate rows or columns:

```c
for (kol = 0; kol < m; kol++) {
  for (red = 0; red < m; red++) {
    if (mat[red][kol] == 100) {
      pom2 = mat[0][kol];

      for (red = 0; red <= m - 2; red++) {
        mat[red][kol] = mat[red + 1][kol];
      }

      mat[m - 1][kol] = pom2;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Save the item from the first row. Move the remaining items up one row. Put the saved item in the last row. That's what that code *would* be doing if it actually compiled (which it doesn't).

Comment: You *must* check the return value from `scanf`.  If the first thing the user enters is not a valid character in an int, then your code exhibits undefined behavior.  Always validate the input, even if the response is merely to abort with an error message.  Be very wary of scanf; it is notoriously difficult to use correctly and is the cause of much confusion.  http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: I have changed the matrix i think it works now but i just want a step by step explanation of the rotation of the matrixes row and I usually use scanf_s    @user3386109

Comment: I have changed the matrix i think it works now but i just want a step by step explanation of the rotation of the matrixes row and I usually use scanf_s @WilliamPursell

Comment: The problem is that you have two `for` loops that both use the same `red` variable. You need two different variables in those two loops.

Comment: are you referring to the loop regarding the rotation of columns or another loop ,the main problem is that i dont know what any of the code in the loop for rotating matrices does @user3386109

Comment: I'm referring to *"This part of the code I do not understand"* at the end of the question. There are two loops that are `for(red=0;red< ... ;red++)`. That doesn't work because there's only one `red` variable, and both loops are trying to use it.

Comment: That is kind of the point because honestly I do not understand either our teacher told us that the code works and students who got As on the exam  did this task like I posted it. The problem is I do not understand the general logic behind how a certain column or row is being rotated so if you have time to explain steps on how to do it it would help me a lot. I learned the previous steps in the task on my own with stack overflow and googling but this step is to me an unknown land. I do not know which variable should i change row or the column and stuff like that @user3386109